# How to get screen width and height?

Tags: android

I know there are many answered questions about how to get screen width and height, but I tried all I could find and I can't get any of them to work.
For example, in this code I get error for context:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: Before onCreate Method initialize your context.

Context cont;
then write the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().get height()/get width().

Answer (score 0):

Try to get `Context` of Application with `getApplicationContext()`.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```